# Why are elements missing in HTML while using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text of labels by

```
url='https://www.hydac.com/shop/en/GP_1000188028'
```

in Product Search section. I've tried all the solutions I know but got nowhere.

Here is my code:

```
items=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'filter-options-item'})
for item in items:
    p=(item.find('label',attrs={'data-bind':'attr: {for: id}'})).find_all('span')
    for q in p:
        print(q.text)
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with, how you fetch the HTML?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` only parses the HTML, it do not handle requesting or rendering what seems to be your issue.

Check the behaviour of the website in your browser, it needs some `time` to render the labels, so you simply have to wait.

**Option#1**

Simply use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait:

```
...
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
...
```

**Option#2**

Use [`selenium waits`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)(recommended) to solve the issue:

```
...
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-bind="text: label"]')))
...
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.hydac.com/shop/en/GP_1000188028'

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-bind="text: label"]')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('#narrow-by-list label')]
```

##### Output

```
['3.5 m/s (piston 2)58',
'0.8 m/s (piston 3)8',
'Aluminium31',
'Carbon steel35',
'NBR / PTFE compound58',
'PUR8',
'10 l6',
'100 l5',
'120 l3',...]
```